# DB2 : Need to get the list of columns and distinct value counts for a given db2 table

Tags: db2, data-profiling

For data profiling purpose , I just need to get the idea if a columns in a given table has values populated or not. For that, I need to get the **list of columns and distinct value counts** for a given db2 table.

Comment: Hi Edayadulla, welcome to StackOverflow. Please include what code you have tried, and the specific question you have. I recommend reading through https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and updating your answer accordingly

Comment: What is your Db2-server platform (Z/OS,  i-series,  Linux/Unix/Windows). The answer differs per platform...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Db2 for Linux, Unix or Windows you could try

```
SELECT TABSCHEMA, TABNAME, COLNAME, COLCARD FROM SYSCAT.COLUMNS
```